# Inserção de inputs criados dimanicamente

Tags: php, jquery, html

Eu estou criando campos dinamicamente assim:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#quantidade').on('change', function(){

      var quantidade = $('#quantidade').val(),
          campos = $('#campos');

      campos.html(''); //aqui eu fiz limpar a div
      for (x = 0; x < quantidade; x++) {
        campos.append('<input type="text" id="campo-'+x+'" />');
      }

    });

});
```

Porém, agora não sei como inserir esses campos no banco, pois irão variar. Aceito sugestões!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom acredito que sua pergunta seja como recuperar isso no PHP é isso?

Para isso adicione [] depois da tag name do seu input.

Vou deixar um exemplo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#quantidade').on('change', function(){

      var quantidade = $('#quantidade').val(),
          campos = $('#campos');

      campos.html(''); //aqui eu fiz limpar a div
      for (x = 0; x < quantidade; x++) {
        campos.append('<input type="text" id="campo-'+x+'" name="campo[]" />');
      }

    });

});
```

> Exemplo no PHP de como recuperar:

```
<?php

for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['campo']; $i++) {
    echo "Campo $i = " . $_POST['campo'][$i];
}
```

Para salvar no banco de dados você pode fazer o uso de uma tabela 1 para N, onde nessa tabela vc coloca o id da informação principal e repete a quantidade de informações que o campo foi inserido com vários inserts.

Caso deseje estudar um pouco sobre Modelagem de dados deixo como dica o site da fundação [Bradesco](https://www.ev.org.br/Paginas/Home.aspx) lá tem vários cursos gratuítos e um deles é sobre a modelagem de banco de dados.

Comment: Obrigada, funcionou corretamente.